# Failed to deploy app via Capistrano, LoadError: cannot load such file -- nokogiri

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, capistrano, nokogiri

I'm using [this tutorial to deploy my app to VPS](https://mattbrictson.com/build-and-deploy-a-rails-vps-part-2). I have created Ubuntu Server on DigitalOcean. I have proceeded all theese steps. However on 11th step I must to write this code:

```
bundle exec cap production deploy
```

It throws me an error:

```
rake aborted!
DEBUG [280721fe]        LoadError: cannot load such file -- nokogiri
DEBUG [280721fe]        /var/www/newsapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/loofah-2.0.2/lib/loofah.rb:3:in `require'
DEBUG [280721fe]        /var/www/newsapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/loofah-2.0.2/lib/loofah.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
DEBUG [280721fe]        /var/www/newsapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rails-html-sanitizer-1.0.2/lib/rails-html-sanitizer.rb:2:in `require'
DEBUG [280721fe]        /var/www/newsapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rails-html-sanitizer-1.0.2/lib/rails-html-sanitizer.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
DEBUG [280721fe]        /var/www/newsapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.0/lib/action_view/helpers/sanitize_helper.rb:3:in `require'
DEBUG [280721fe]        /var/www/newsapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.0/lib/action_view/helpers/sanitize_helper.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
DEBUG [280721fe]        /var/www/newsapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.0/lib/action_view/helpers/text_helper.rb:32:in `<module:TextHelper>'
DEBUG [280721fe]        /var/www/newsapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.0/lib/action_view/helpers/text_helper.rb:29:in `<module:Helpers>'
DEBUG [280721fe]        /var/www/newsapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.0/lib/action_view/helpers/text_helper.rb:6:in `<module:ActionView>'
DEBUG [280721fe]        /var/www/newsapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.0/lib/action_view/helpers/text_helper.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
DEBUG [280721fe]        /var/www/newsapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.0/lib/action_view/helpers/form_tag_helper.rb:18:in `<module:FormTagHelper>'
DEBUG [280721fe]        /var/www/newsapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.0/lib/action_view/helpers/form_tag_helper.rb:14:in `<module:Helpers>'
DEBUG [280721fe]        /var/www/newsapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.0/lib/action_view/helpers/form_tag_helper.rb:8:in `<module:ActionView>'
DEBUG [280721fe]        /var/www/newsapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.0/lib/action_view/helpers/form_tag_helper.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
DEBUG [280721fe]        /var/www/newsapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.0/lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:4:in `require'
DEBUG [280721fe]        /var/www/newsapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.0/lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:4:in `<top (required)>' 
DEBUG [280721fe]        /var/www/newsapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.0/lib/action_view/helpers.rb:50:in `<module:Helpers>'
DEBUG [280721fe]        /var/www/newsapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.0/lib/action_view/helpers.rb:4:in `<module:ActionView>'
DEBUG [280721fe]        /var/www/newsapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.0/lib/action_view/helpers.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
DEBUG [280721fe]        /var/www/newsapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.3.1/lib/sprockets/rails/legacy_asset_tag_helper.rb:7:in `<module:LegacyAssetTagHelper>'
DEBUG [280721fe]        /var/www/newsapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.3.1/lib/sprockets/rails/legacy_asset_tag_helper.rb:6:in `<module:Rails>'
DEBUG [280721fe]        /var/www/newsapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.3.1/lib/sprockets/rails/legacy_asset_tag_helper.rb:4:in `<module:Sprockets>'
DEBUG [280721fe]        /var/www/newsapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.3.1/lib/sprockets/rails/legacy_asset_tag_helper.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
DEBUG [280721fe]        /var/www/newsapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.3.1/lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:54:in `require'
DEBUG [280721fe]        /var/www/newsapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.3.1/lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:54:in `<module:Helper>'
DEBUG [280721fe]        /var/www/newsapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.3.1/lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:7:in `<module:Rails>'
DEBUG [280721fe]        /var/www/newsapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.3.1/lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:6:in `<module:Sprockets>'
DEBUG [280721fe]        /var/www/newsapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.3.1/lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
DEBUG [280721fe]        /var/www/newsapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.3.1/lib/sprockets/railtie.rb:6:in `require'
DEBUG [280721fe]        /var/www/newsapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.3.1/lib/sprockets/railtie.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
DEBUG [280721fe]        /var/www/newsapp/releases/20150710090114/config/application.rb:10:in `require'
DEBUG [280721fe]        /var/www/newsapp/releases/20150710090114/config/application.rb:10:in `<top (required)>'
DEBUG [280721fe]        /var/www/newsapp/releases/20150710090114/Rakefile:4:in `require'
DEBUG [280721fe]        /var/www/newsapp/releases/20150710090114/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
DEBUG [280721fe]        (See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Ubuntu failed to load `nokogiri`. I happens when It tries to run `rake assets:precompile` command.

I have written this project on Windows 7 and uploaded it to my BitBucket repository. I thought that Capistrano runs `bundle install` by itself and changes `Gemfile.lock`.

My local computer running on Windows 7 x64 uses Ruby 2.1.5.

My VPS running on Ubuntu Server 14.04 x64 uses Ruby 2.2.0.

What do I need to do?

==== Update ====

I thought that, because I have written this app on Windows and trying to upload it to Ubuntu, my `Gemfile.lock` will be different. I have deleted it and tried to upload it to my VPS and it says that It can not run my app because I have not `Gemfile.lock`.

==== Update ====

I have restarted my VPS. I heard that Nokogiri has conflicts with 2.2 Verisons of Ruby so I have installed 2.1.6 version. Still it gives me this error on precompile.

==== Update ====

I have found that inmy Ubuntu **every rake task** that I want to start throws me this error.

Comment: Capistrano doesn't do anything by its own,,,if you specify this in deploy.rb,only then it will do it else it wont

Comment: I have looked on console logs and I have found that it runs bundler `Running /usr/bin/env bundle install --path /var/www/newsapp/shared/bundle --without development test --deployment --quiet`. However It still gives error on precompile. Do this because my project was written on Windows?

Comment: Do you have the output from `bundle install`? `nokogiri` requires `libxml2` and `libxslt` - do you have those installed on your VPS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found solution and I think it is not good.

In my `Gemfile.lock` I have deleted all `-64x-mingw` strings, leaving only name and verison number of my gems.

In platform I simply wrote `ruby` instead of `mingw`.

Well... that worked.

Heroku deletes Windows `Gemfile.lock` and generates new one automatically. Is it possible to send to capistrano that kind of commands?

Answer (score 0):

I read that Nokogiri had some issues with the last version of Ruby (2.2), may be you should consider to rollback to Ruby 2.1 on you server.

Comment: Link to how to rollback or example please :)

Comment: I saw in the tutorial you used that the guy suggest to install ruby via `rbenv`.
I'm not very familiar with it because I prefer to use RVM but you should definitely find you answer in the official rbenv doc:
https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv

Hope it helps

Comment: I have restarted my VPS ans installed 2.1.6 version of Ruby. It still gives me this error.